# Code meant to copy rows from one sheet to another if there are specific strings in 2 columns keeps crashing

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

Whenever I run this code it crashes. Please help!

This is what the code is supposed to do. For an unknown amount of filled rows, if column G of worksheet "Current PM" contains either "AS-001", "EE-001", "MM-001", "OS-001", "CO-001", "DO-001", "FO-001", "FD-001", "TO-001", "IP-001"
and column H contains "PDR" then copy the row from "Current PM" sheet into "Print_Current PMs" sheet.

```
Sub Sort4Printing()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

i = 2: j = 2

While IsEmpty(Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 1)) = False

If Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 8) = "PDR" Then

If Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 7) = "AS-001" Or Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 7) = "EE-001" Or Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 7) = "MM-001" Or Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 7) = "OS-001" Or Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 7) = "FO-001" Or Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 7) = "FD-001" Or Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 7) = "TO-001" Or Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 7) = "IP-001" Then

Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(j, 1) = Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 1)
Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(j, 2) = Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 2)
Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(j, 3) = Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 12)
Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(j, 4) = Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 4)
Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(j, 5) = Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 5)
Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(j, 6) = Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 6)
Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(j, 7) = Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 7)
Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(j, 8) = Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 8)
Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(j, 9) = Worksheets("Current PM").Cells(i, 10)



  i=i+1: j=j+1
End If
End If
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: `Whenever I run this code it crashes.` Is not very helpful.   Please explain in more concise verbiage what exactly does it do? when does it do it?  Where in the code does it stop?  Also  a [`With` block](http://www.homeandlearn.org/with_end_with.html) would help shorten the number of key strokes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While, I don't know *exactly* why it crashes, I can offer some clean-up and techniques that will cut down on the processing of the code.

1. No need to iterate through 2 variables, since they are both the same counter
2. Dimension the counting variable as type `Long`, as if there are more than 32,767 rows an Integer variable will fall due to it's byte limitation.
3. Using a `With` block will help when working with objects, instead of always referencing the object
4. Using a `Select Case` statement for multiple conditions on the same object will (I believe) take less processing then multiple `If Or` conditions. It's also *a lot* more reader friendly.

See refactored code:

```
Sub Sort4Printing()

Dim i As Long

i = 2

With Worksheets("Current PM")

    While Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1))

        If .Cells(i, 8) = "PDR" Then

            Select Case .Cells(i, 7)

                Case Is = "AS-001", "EE-001", "MM-001", "OS-001", "FO-001", "FD-001", "TO-001", "IP-001"

                    Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(i, 1)
                    Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(i, 2) = .Cells(i, 2)
                    Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(i, 3) = .Cells(i, 12)
                    Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(i, 4) = .Cells(i, 4)
                    Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(i, 5)
                    Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(i, 6) = .Cells(i, 6)
                    Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(i, 7) = .Cells(i, 7)
                    Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(i, 8) = .Cells(i, 8)
                    Worksheets("Print_Current PMs").Cells(i, 9) = .Cells(i, 10)

            End Select

        End If

        i = i + 1

    Wend

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As to why it crashes, and I suppose you to mean it goes into an infinite loop that you can not exit unless you force excel to shut down.

The line `i=i+1: j=j+1` needs to be outside both if statements.

```
...  
End If
End If

i=i+1: j=j+1
Wend

End Sub
```

As you have it when it encounters a line that does not meet the If Requirements it does not increment so it continues to test the same line over and over again till you get tired and shut down Excel.

That being said this is just for information.  Scott Holtzman's answer has better methodology and a good place to learn many things that are lacking.